# Get most commented status in facebook using fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get all the status which are most commented during the last month for some user.I tried using fql.But could not find a suitable fql query for that.I want to know that is it possible ?

Comment: Using fql,I think it is not possible.But using using graph API you can fetch all statuses and from that result JSON you can apply some looping for getting comments and based on the comments count you can get the most commented status.Try https://graph.facebook.com/id/statuses

Comment: Yes, we can get all the status and comments count using graph Api..    thank you for your suggestions